# Faulty tail syntax or grep command?

Tags: bash

I've been given the following code:

```
tail -fn0 /var/log/messages | \  
while read line ; do  
       echo "$line" | grep "test"  
       if [ $? = 0 ]  
       echo "Running information gathering"  
       then  
etc...etc
```

What it's supposed to do is continually monitor the added lines of the "/var/tmp/messages" file and if one contains the word "test" then execute the rest of the script and exit when done.
It's executing the rest of the script as soon as **any** line is added to the messages file, irrespective of line content. I've added echo commands, and $line contains the new log file line correctly. I've tried changing the test "$? = 0" to "$? = 1" but it makes no difference.
Could someone please give me a pointer?

Thanks @TomFenech

Comment: `$?` returns an integer. And integer comparison is done with `-eq`, `-ge`, etc, instead of `=`, `!=`, etc.

Comment: However, `[ $? = 0 ]` and `[ $? -eq 0 ]` should have the same result, no matter what the value of `$?`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of using a loop, you can make things a lot simpler by just using grep:

```
tail -fn0 /var/log/messages | grep -q test
echo "Running information gathering"
# rest of script
```

`grep -q` exits after the first match, so your script will continue as soon as the first match is found.

Comment: Nice! I tested it with `for i in {1..100}; do echo $i >> a; sleep 1; done` in one tab and `tail -fn0 a | grep -q 5` in the other one and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it as well ;)

Comment: @Tom Fenech Whilst the above works beautifully thanks, it breaks the script later because the original $line info is now missing, and is tested later. I've tried the following:  `tail -fn0 /var/log/messages | grep -q "CPU utilization" | grep -q "exceeded threshold"
read lineFPC=$(echo $line | awk 'END { print substr($8,1,1) }')
PIC=$(echo $line | awk 'END { print substr($11,1,1) }')
echo FPC $FPC
echo PIC $PIC`
but it just sits there never executing the rest of the script.

Comment: @Andy That's because `grep -q` does not produce any output. One option would be to use `grep -m1` instead, which exits after one match and prints the output, so it can be used further along the chain. However, to be honest it looks like you could do what you want using a single awk program. I think that this solves the problem as it was originally specified. If your requirements are actually different, maybe you should ask a new question.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the advice Tom, have done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754660/tail-fn0-and-variable

Answer (score 2):

In BASH you can use glob matches and avoid `grep`:

```
tail -fn0 /var/log/messages | 
while read -r line; do  
    if [[ "$line" == *test* ]]; then
       echo "Running information gathering"  
    fi  
done
```

**PS:** You could use `grep -q` instead to get correct exit status based on the successful match being found.

Comment: `grep` returns non-zero when it doesn't find a match. I would use `grep -q` in this case to silence the output, exit earlier, and explicitly request the exit code but this should work anyway.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Yes you're right, it was a silly mistake on my part. Thanks.