# Tail -Fn0 and variable

Tags: bash

This follows on from [Faulty tail syntax or grep command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737639/faulty-tail-syntax-or-grep-command/26738003?noredirect=1#comment42090714_26738003) but I'm reading a live log entries for given conditions and when they're met continuing the execution of the rest of the script. I'm using this:

```
tail -Fn0 /var/log/messages | grep -q "CPU utilization" | grep -q "exceeded threshold"  
FPC=$(echo $line | awk 'END { print substr($8,1,1) }')  
PIC=$(echo $line | awk 'END { print substr($11,1,1) }')  
echo FPC $FPC  
echo PIC $PIC  
echo "Running information gathering"...and rest of script.
```

Which works perfectly for the conditions detection and further execution, but I don't have the log entry to test for the FPC and PIC variables. I've tried wrapping the tail statement thus:

```
line=$(tail -Fn0 /var/log/messages | grep -q "CPU utilization" | grep -q "exceeded threshold")
```

but grep -q exits silently and the $line variable is blank. I've tried:

```
line=$(tail -Fn0 /var/log/messages | grep -m1 "CPU utilization" | grep -m1 "exceeded threshold")
```

which doesn't work until I attempt to CONTROL-C out of the script. Then it works fine and continues perfectly. Can someone help please?

I need the variables FPC and PIC later in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't need these variables later on, you could do something like this:

```
tail -Fn0 /var/log/messages | \
awk '/CPU utilization/ && /exceeded threshold/ { 
     print "FPC", substr($8,1,1); print "PIC", substr($11,1,1); exit }'
```

When the line matches both patterns, print the two parts of it that you are interested in and exit.

If you do need the variables, you could do something like this instead:

```
line=$(tail -Fn0 /var/log/messages | awk '/CPU utilization/&&/exceeded threshold/{print;exit}')
FPC=$(echo "$line" | awk '{ print substr($8,1,1) }')
PIC=$(echo "$line" | awk '{ print substr($11,1,1) }')
```